# how to download pdf with nodejs and expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, pdfkit

I'm using [this](https://github.com/baptistejamin/node-microinvoice) GitHub repo to generate pdf invoices.
code looks something like this :

```
let myInvoice = new MicroInvoice({
  ... pdf content obj goes here
});

  const file = await myInvoice.generate("example.pdf");
  const fileType = "application/pdf";

  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Disposition": `attachment;"`,
    "Content-Type": fileType,
  });

  const download = Buffer.from(file, "base64");
  res.end(download);
```

But this code gives the following Error: could not handle the request.
What could be the issue here?

EDIT : Generate pdf function looks like something like this :

```
 generate(output) {
    let _stream    = null;

    this.document = new PDFDocument({
      size : "A4"
    });

    this.loadCustomFonts();
    this.generateHeader();
    this.generateDetails("customer");
    this.generateDetails("seller");
    this.generateParts();
    this.generateLegal();

    if (typeof output === "string" || (output || {}).type === "file") {
      let _path = "";

      if (typeof output === "string") {
        _path = output;
      } else {
        _path = output.path;
      }

      _stream = fs.createWriteStream(output);

      this.document.pipe(_stream);
      this.document.end();
    } else {
      this.document.end();
      return this.document;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.document.on("end", () => {
        return resolve();
      });

      this.document.on("error", () => {
        return reject();
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of the library, the `.generate()` method doesn't return anything, so your `file` variable will be `undefined` (I also have no idea what the `Buffer.from()` is doing…).

Instead, you can use [`res.attachment()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.attachment) and [`res.sendFile()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile):

```
await myInvoice.generate("example.pdf");
res.attachment().sendFile('example.pdf', { root : __dirname });
```

Be aware that every request will overwrite the file, which may not be what you want.

**EDIT**: looking closer, you can make `generate()` return the document by not passing any arguments to it. In that case, you can prevent a local file from being written:

```
const doc = myInvoice.generate();

doc.pipe( res.attachment('invoice.pdf') );
```

(untested)

Comment: generate(output) will call fs.createWriteStream(output), so I wonder if there's a way without actually saving the file

Comment: I'm looking to send file without saving locally

Comment: @MANnDAaR see edit